# Architecture for implementing functionalities of two classes to a third class using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a package named org.TestDemo and created 3 different test scripts using selenium webdriver which are given below;

```
1. LoginTest.java
2. Privillege.java
3. Alerts.java
```

In LoginTest.java class I have created positive test scenarios for login functionality in Privillege.java class I have done some user privilege scenarios and in Alerts.java ,provided some alert functionality.

When I run Alerts.java class ,I just want to call both the other two classes from 
Alerts.Java class to inherit the functionality in LoginTest.java & Privillege.java

So what architecture should I follow to implement this task ?

Comment: Why do you think you need to extend LoginTest and Privillege? You can just create instances of them and invoke needed methods. Or Alerts contains methods from both classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand what you need, but instead of inherit *LoginTest* and *Privillege* - can u just use/call their functionality into your *Alerts* (keep instances of LoginTest and Privillege)? If they are in same package - this shouldn't be a problem. In my experience I've always consider creation and usage of BaseTest.java wich helps me to share test_logic in my architecture.

In case you need some more complex logic you can always try [use Decorator](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/11/decorator-design-pattern-java-example.html) or [try Mediator](http://www.journaldev.com/1730/mediator-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial).